# Cakephp Events registered but not firing

Tags: php, cakephp, events

hi Guy's like many people I'm having dificulties Implementing Events into my Cakephp Application It would be really cool if somebody could point out where I messed im Using CakePHP v2.7
I allso followed Martin Bean's Tutorial on the Subject:
http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/11/22/getting-to-grips-with-cakephps-events-system/

---

My code is as Follows:
App/Event/UserListener.php

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');

class UserListener implements CakeEventListener {

public function implementedEvents() {
    #@:off;
    return array(
        'Model.User.test' => 'test',
        'Model.User.created' => 'sendActivationEmail',
    );
    #@:on;
}

public function test($event) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        echo "string<br />";
    }
    CakeLog::write('CakeEvents', 'Testevent Fired');
}

public function sendActivationEmail($event) {

}

}
```

in App/Model/User.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('Role', 'Model');
App::uses('Clroute', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'Event');

public function afterFind($results, $primary = true) {
    $Event = new CakeEvent('Model.User.test', $this, array(
    #@:off;
            'id' => 66,
            'data' => 'ppx'
        )
    );
    #@:on;
    CakeLog::write('CakeEvents', 'Testevent dispatch in UserModel');
    $this -> getEventManager() -> dispatch($Event);
    if ($results[0]['Salon']['id'] == null) {
        $results[0]['Salon'] = FALSE;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

And last but not least in App/Config/bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
App::uses('UserListener', 'Event');
$user = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$user->getEventManager()->attach(new UserListener());
```

It would be great if you could Help me out because I'm really Stuck there and Cakephp's Documentation on the subject is kind of hazy allso :-/

Big THX in advance!!
regards Michael

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? An alternative tutorial on Cake Events: http://andy-carter.com/blog/events-in-cakephp-2-using-the-observer-pattern

Comment: Also check whether you are operating on the expected objects, in your `afterFind()` method, have a look at `$this->getEventManager()->listeners()` to see whether your listener is actually registered.

Comment: the errorlog doesent list any new errors if i try to dispatch a event...

Comment: I Got it the The UserListener did not get attatched to the Model I fixed It by attatching the Listener directly in the Model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against directly attaching the event listeners in the model (as suggested in your own answer). This somewhat defeats the point of using events in the first place. One of the strengths of using events is that it allows you to develop more extendable code that can be easily overridden; attaching the listener directly from the model goes against this concept.

If you're listener doesn't appear to be called despite attaching it to your model in `bootstrap.php` you may need to globally attach it:-

```
// In app/Config/bootstrap.php
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');
App::uses('UserListener', 'Lib/Event');
CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(new UserListener());
```

This is instead of attaching it directly to the `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

scrap the code in App/Config/bootstrap.php instead add this line to your Model:

```
$user->getEventManager()->attach(new UserListener());
```

and enshure to add this to your Model aswell:

```
App::uses('UserListener', 'Event');
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend attaching your listeners directly from a model as it couples the code. One of the strengths of using events is that it allows you to develop more extendable code that can be easily overridden; attaching the listener directly from the model goes against this concept and almost makes the use of the listener redundant.